# Initialize Matrix of size 'X' by 'X' with values of '0'

Tags: powershell, matrix

I'm trying to initiate a matrix of 10x10 where the value of each cell is 0. But it looks like it's failing to create a second column when I initialize the matrix in this way.

```
$m = ,@(0) * 10
$m += ,@(0) * 10
$m | %{"$_"}
```

However, this method will set the rows correctly (but not initialize the cells at 0 like I want)

```
$m = ,@(1..10) 
$m += ,@(1..10) 
$m | %{"$_"}
```

expected output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

And I would rather not iterate over the cells to reset them.
An explanation of why it only makes a single column when I do it the 1st way would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add somthing together, the left side of the expression will decide the result. Since the left side of the expression is an array, it will merge the array's content with the new value. 10 arrays + 10 arrays = your `$m`-array now contains 20 single-item arrays. It is a two-dimensional array/matrix, but it's 20x1 and not 2x10.

```
$m.Count
20

$m[0].Count
1
```

Be aware that arrays are reference type, so you are creating 10 copies of the reference (pointer) to the same single-item array, which means this will happen:

```
$m[0][0] = 1
$m | % {"$_"}
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

I would use foreach-loops to create ten arrays of ten items (using 3 in example to shorten demo).

```
$m = 1..3 | % { ,(1..3 | % { 0 }) }

$m.Count
3

$m[0].Count
3

$m[0][0] = 1
$m[2][1] = 1
$m | % {"$_"}
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 1 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, and the explanation. I still don't quite understand then why the 2nd solution I had does work... It's still an array added to an array.. but the result is a 2x10 matrix.

Comment: The first solution adds 20 arrays to the `$m`-array. The second creates two arrays containing 10 items (1-10), which is what you wanted. There's a difference between 12 bottles and two 6-packs. `$m = ,(@(0) * 10)` would be the same as the second solution (and it would also work fine, though it's more messy)

Answer (score 1):

[Frode F.'s helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43380337/45375) explains the problem with your solution attempt well.

However, you can **efficiently create true, initialized-to-`0` multi-dimensional arrays using `New-Object`**:

```
$arr2d = New-Object 'int[,]' (10, 10) # Create a 10 x 10 [int] array, initialized to all 0s
```

**Caveats:**

- **Attempting to *append* to such an array with `+=` quietly *flattens* it** to a *single*-dimensional one, with the new element(s) appended - curiously, even type-constraining the variable (`[int[,]] $arr2d = New-Object ...`) cannot prevent that.
- **Range expressions such as `0..2` cannot be used** in the indices of such an array.

**Examine** the resulting array:

Get the type:

```
> $arr2d.GetType().Name
Int32[,]
```

Get the rank (dimension count):

```
> $arr2d.Rank
2
```

Get the count of elements of each dimension:

```
> 0..($arr2d.Rank-1) | % { $arr2d.GetLength($_) }
10
10
```

Set some elements:

```
$arr2d[0,1] = 1; $arr2d[4,5] = 5; $arr2d[8,9] = 9
```

Enumerate the elements in matrix form:

```
> 0..$arr2d.GetUpperBound(0) | 
    % { $dim1=$_; (0..$arr2d.GetUpperBound(1) | % { $arr2d[$dim1, $_] }) -join ' ' }
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```